# How to detect activity start

Tags: java, android, android-activity

How i can detect activity start? I want my code run's every time that activity start's (startup) not onCreate that run's only one time. How i can do this?

Comment: Please do some research before asking. Have a look at the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to put that in `onResume()`.  This will be called each time your `Activity` comes visible again.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [the Android Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) you will see that overriding the onResume() method will allow your code to execute each and every time